# Float right position seems to be floating in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out why this box is floating down a bit from alignment with it's neighbor. The same code is in use inside the main boxes for the content, so It's a big puzzling, and the parents have nothing special that should be messing with the alignment.

http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/

I tried vertical-align knowing it wouldn't work with the elements anyway. I'm just confused. Again!

**CSS**

```
            .right-large-box {
                float: right;
                width: 300px;
                height: auto;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                vertical-align: top;
                top: 0;
            }

            .left-large-box {
                height: auto;
                padding: 0;
                margin-right: 310px;
                vertical-align: top;
                top: 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top margin of 20px on `.large-box` is pushing it down inside its container. Remove that and it will sit at the top like you want.

Comment: I'm assuming that they still want the margin. I'd suggest placing the 20px margin on the bottom(of `.large-box`) instead i.e. `margin: auto 20px 20px;`

Comment: It already has 20px margin on bottom as well as the top. I think `margin: 0 auto 20px;` is the desired result. Either that or remove the bottom margin as well and put it on `.right-large-box` instead.

Comment: Ahh I see, I've interpreted 'remove' as in to get rid of it (`margin: auto 20px;`) when what you meant is to set the top margin to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `float: right;` inside the `.right-large-box` class, you should apply `float` for `.left-large-box` class too. So it should be:

```
.left-large-box {
   float:left; /* add this one */
   height: auto;
   padding: 0;
   margin-right: 310px;
   vertical-align: top;
   top: 0; /* this one actually can be removed */
}
```

I think you also can remove the `top:0;` unless if you have set `position:relative/absolute` to those classes.